# Finding the derivative of an integral with variable in the bound and in the integrand

Tags: calculus

If I have
$$
F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)g(x-t)dt,
$$
how do I find $ F'(x) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two sources of variation: The change in the upper limit, which by the fundamnetal theorem of calculus will just give a change in the integral of 
$f(x)g(x-x) = f(x)g(0)$, and the change in the integrand, which itself will be integrated over.  Under some fairly mild assumptions about the natures of $f$ and $g$, the integration and derivative can be interchanged for that second part.  The answer is thus
$$ \frac{dF(x)}{dx} = f(x)g(0) + \int_0^x f(t) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x-t) \, dt$$

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

$F'(x) = f(x)g(0) + \int_0^x f(t) g'(x-t) dt$.

Comment: What changed? ${}{}$